# Android proprietary app including Apache-2.0 licensed code from Google

Tags: licensing, android, google, billing, apache2

My Android app contains some Apache-2.0 licensed code from Google (in-app billing example) and links to `com.android.vending.billing` library in the form of a `InAppBillingFile.aidl` file (same license?).

I would like to know what I have to do for my app to be license compliant, i.e. what to show in the About section, what files to include and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your app merely links to the library, it is not considered a derived work by the Apache 2.0 license. This means that you are completely free in the choice of license for your own code.

For distributing an Apache 2.0 licensed library, the main condition is that you inform your users about the license. The easiest way to do that without risk of confusion is to mention in the About section that you use this library and that it is available under the Apache 2.0 license, with a human readable link to the license text.
If you have the full text of your own license/EULA in there, then you should also reproduce the complete text of the Apache 2.0 license.

Comment: Are you saying that if I developer a closed source app for a customer (which wants it to be freely downloadable on Google Play) I do not have to put in an "about" box where I state I use a specific Apache 2.0 library? This contradicts what I have read other places, so I am interested in the source (since I personally have not found a good way to have "about" buttons   cases similar to the one I describe)

Comment: @Tom: I am not familiar with how the various stores work and it can be that adding an about box to your app is the only practical way to comply with the requirement of informing your users about the library.